# Optimus - still doesn't work?

Tags: 13.10, nvidia, kernel, nvidia-optimus

I was using Ubuntu 12.04 with Bumblebee for a while.
Since I've bought an SSD, I've decided to install Windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.10.
Now, AFAIR Ubuntu 13.10 has 3.11.* kernel. I read, that with some version of the 3.12 kernel Nvidia Optimus graphics is finally supported - it can be switched off to save battery life automatically. So I decided to upgrade the Linux kernel in my Ubuntu. At this moment, I have 3.13.2-031302-generic. So Optimus graphics should right now work out of the box, right?

The thing is, it's not. My laptop (Asus K53SV) is still overheating, so obviously Nvidia GT 540M is on.

Should I do something after upgrading kernel to make it work?

**EDIT**
I read this page: http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/Optimus/
When I type: `cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` it turns out that my discrete card has status DynPwr all the time, instead of DynOff. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

By what I know 12.04.3 have it working out of box with driver 319 as you can se in

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2174499

it is interesting as it use prime what can lead to better performance... 
Im on 13.10 and relying on bumblebee...

Without bumblebee my Dell overheat too as the nvidia is on... Even if doing nothing at all

Update:

**well I make some extra simple research on google and found more info**

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/using-nvidia-graphics-drivers-with.html

**as said in webupd8... Apparently 13.10 have support, but isn't out of box by what they can see, because it have some issues still**

Comment: But shouldn't it works out of the box with this kernel and nouveau?

Comment: But you are still talking about primus and nvidia prop drivers - but it should work with nouveau without installing prop drivers with this kernel. Or maybe am I wrong? Also look at this ' Currently, the Nvidia GPU can be used to render the desktop, but there's no power saving yet. That means you can for instance play games or watch videos using hardware acceleration.' - this is not what I want to achieve.

Comment: But it work with nouveau, I was talking about proprietary because generally it will improve energy consumption/performance, they only didn't talk about 3.12 dynamic switch initial support, as stated it would work with nvidia-prime package, but I would not expect much precision from this initial implementation of automation

Comment: Are you sure it works with nouveau in 3.13 kernel? My laptop is much hotter than with bumblebee, so I assume that nvidia card is still working all the time.

Comment: not out of box... you still need to decide between prime and bumblebee(VirtualGL or primus). Only prime by what I know will make use of newer kernell ability to switch by itself. the two approach without 3.12 kernel or newer will need manual switch... and by default 13.10 isnt using neither prime neither bumblebee.

Comment: Well, I've just installed 14.04 daily + nvidia-prime 0.5.5 + nvidia prop driers 331 - works like a charm!